# kill all queries - MySQL

Tags: mysql, command-line

Sometimes during a SNAFU I have to run `kill query xxxxxxx` twenty or thirty times. Any sort of `kill all` command I am missing?

On account of how I don't like typing.

Comment: restart the server?

Comment: @DTest - can that be done with a query? I don't have direct server access.

Comment: This is a question that can come in handy for other developers and DBAs (+1) !!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the Linux command line

```
for PROC_TO_KILL in `mysql -h... -u... -p... -A --skip-column-names -e"SHOW PROCESSLIST" | grep -v "system user" | awk '{print $1}'` ; do mysql -h... -u... -p... -A --skip-column-names -e"KILL QUERY ${PROC_TO_KILL}" ; done
```

You can change the grep option in the header of the for loop to locate a specific user or specific string in the query.

If you have MySQL 5.1 where the processlist is in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA, you can do this to generate the KILL QUERY commands in bulk from within the mysql client:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('KILL QUERY ',id,';') SEPARATOR ' ') KillQuery
FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE user<>'system user'\G
```

You can do WHERE clauses against the INFO field to look for a specific query, the TIME field against long running queries, or the DB field against a specific database.

Answer (score 6):

```
mysql> select concat('KILL ',id,';') from information_schema.processlist where user='root' into outfile '/tmp/a.txt';
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> source /tmp/a.txt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/05/21/mass-killing-of-mysql-connections/

Comment: I actually like this approach because it can be done within the confines of the mysql client regardless of Linux or Windows. +1 !!!