# Incomplete dumps using mysqldump

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, mysql-5.7

I am running Mysql server with master and slave replication. From past few days i found that backups on my master server are incomplete.

When i ran manually on master it's returning the below error

**"mysqldump: Error 1317: Query execution was interrupted when dumping table `table_name` at row: 36705562"**

Command i am using to take backups

**mysqldump -u dbdump -p dbname --routines --single-transaction --lock-tables=false --max-allowed-packet=512M --master-data=2 -q -C -E -e -f -R | gzip -c > backup.sql.gz**

Ideally i am using the same command on both master and slave, but it's failing on master.

I tried to do backup from remote machine but the same error.

In /etc/my.cnf --> max packet size is set to 512M

Answer (score 1):

I have dealt with this in the past.

- `Jan 04, 2018` : [MySQL - MySQLDump problems with large table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194580/mysql-mysqldump-problems-with-large-table/194620#194620)
- `Jan 12, 2012` : [Client times out, while MySQL query remains running?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10578/client-times-out-while-mysql-query-remains-running/10592#10592)

There are three(3) aspects you need to consider

## ASPECT #1 : Table Corruption

Please take note of the row number `36705562`. *If that row number comes back in the error message every single time your mysqldump fails on that table, then maybe you can suspect data corruption*.

## ASPECT #2 : Networking

I suggested increasing networking timeout like this

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL net_read_timeout = 31536000;
mysql> SET GLOBAL net_write_timeout = 31536000;
```

Basically, this will make a DB Connection sit longer until all data from a SELECT comes.

If your get a different row number with every mysqldump attempt, this suggests mysqldump connection is able to move along the large table and just timeout and some random point.

## ASPECT #3 : [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) (Optional)

While 512M is a good size, the maximum value for the [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) is 1G. It does not hurt to increase it to 1G for mysqldump. Why ??? The MySQL Packet is not sized by [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet). It is sized by [net_buffer_length](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_buffer_length) (default size is 16K). MySQL will dynamically stretch a MySQL Packet up to whatever [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) is set to and then shrink back to its original size when data transmission through the MySQL Packet is done. You should set [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) to 1G or 1024M.

Comment: Tried with max_allowed_packet=1024M got the same error but for different table. Should try this by changing read and write time out  values. I cross check those values on slave server both are set to (30 and 60) but it's doing good.

Comment: Please don't forget to check the error message and note at what table mysqldump fails and at what row.

Comment: When using `mysqldump` I put the global variables in the `/etc/my.cnf` and restarted the server. Otherwise they are only for the current mysql session.